# PostgreSQL: Serializable transactions with GRANT/DROP role

Tags: postgresql, sqltransaction

I have been reading a lot about serializable transactions in Postgres, but came across an issue that I haven't been able to resolve. Let's assume that I have two Postgres sessions A and B from different psql processes, and that before starting any transactions, I create roles `role1` and `role2`

```
myuser=# CREATE ROLE role1 ;
CREATE ROLE
myuser=# CREATE ROLE role2 ;
CREATE ROLE
```

At this point, I can start transactions in both of the sessions via `myuser=# BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE ;` and verify that both sessions see both roles, via `SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles;`

Let's assume that I drop the role `role2` from the session B, verify that it's not shown and commit:

```
myuser=# DROP ROLE role2 ;
DROP ROLE
myuser=# SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles;
                    rolname                    | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolbypassrls | rolconfig |  oid
-----------------------------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+-------
 role1                                         | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           | 16563
myuser=# commit ;
COMMIT
```

Now, let's go back to session A:

Even after dropping `role2` and committing inside session B, we can still see that the transaction in session A still sees both roles (as expected, as this is serializable):

```
myuser=# SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles;
                    rolname                    | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolbypassrls | rolconfig |  oid
-----------------------------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------
 role1                                         | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           | 16563
 role2                                         | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           | 16564
```

Now, let's try the `GRANT` command. Here is the weird part:

```
myuser=# GRANT role2 TO role1 ;
ERROR:  role "role2" does not exist
```

Right before running the `GRANT`, we can see that both roles `role1` and `role2` exist, but now we see such error. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With “normal” (i.e. non-catalog) tables conflicting operations like this would lead to a *serialization error*. While a serializable transaction *sees* an old state of the database, any attempt to *modify* a value that has been changed since would lead to such an error.

What makes this case different is that the tables that store roles and role membership (`pg_authid` and `pg_auth_members`) are *catalog tables* (even *shared catalogs* since roles apply to all databases), and for these processing and error messages are slightly different.

It is good and necessary that the operation fails, even if the error message is surprising.